# Find and replace semi-common strings in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to find a semi-common occurring string and remove all other data in the column. Pandas and Re have been imported. For instance, I have dataframe...

```
>>>df
COLUMN COUNT   DATA
           1   this row RA-123: data 8b43a
           2   here RA-5372: data 94h63c
```

I need to keep just the RA-'number that follows' and remove everything before and after. The numbers that follow are not always the same length and the 'RA-' string does not always occur in the same position. There is a colon after every instance that can be used as a delimiter.

I tried this (a friend wrote the regex search piece for me because I am not familiar with it).

```
df.assign(DATA= df['DATA'].str.extract(re.search('RA[^:]+')))
```

But python returned

```
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need for `re`, just pass the regex to `extract`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use acapturing group with extract:

```
df['DATA'].str.extract(r'(RA-\d+)')
```

Here, `(RA-\d+)` is a capturing group matching `RA`, then a hyphen and then one or more digits.

You may use your own pattern, but you still need to wrap it with capturing parentheses, `r'(RA[^:]+)'`.

Comment: Wiktor, this works great and that was a great explanation. Thank you. By any chance would you know how I would declare a column name that has a space in the header (IE: 'RA ID') in place of the argument after the df.assign? (Currently 'DATA=')

Comment: You can use the way I did in my answer. `df['RA ID'] = df['DATA'].str.extract(r'(RA-\d+)')`

Comment: Yes, if you want to just assign the results to a new column use `df['RA ID'] = df['DATA'].str.extract(r'(RA-\d+)', expand=False)` or even `df['RA ID'] = df['DATA'].str.extract(r'(RA-\d+)', expand=False).fillna('')`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), you don't need the `re.search` method. You just call `df[DATA] = df['DATA'].str.extract(r'RA[^:]+'))`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier, no need for `re` here.

Other answers addressed well how to use `extract` directly. However, to answer your specificly, if you really want to use `re`, the way to go is to use `re.compile` instead of `re.search`.

```
df.assign(DATA= df['DATA'].str.extract(re.compile(regex_str)))
```